# How to match every folder but one in grunt?

Tags: gruntjs

I'm using grunt to copy files from source folder to dest folder. for this specific, I'm copying everything inside the main-folder, but I don't want "folder-X" and "folder-Z" copied with the rest of the folders that are inside the main-folder.

In my Grunt:

```
copy: {
        dist: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd:'<%= app %>/',
                src: ['main-folder/**', '!**/*.scss'],
                dest: '<%= dist %>/'
            }]
        },
    },
```

Comment: can't you just `src: ['main-folder/**', '!**/*.scss', '!main-folder/folder-X', '!main-folder/folder-Y']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can not not just adjust your `src` directory list as you have done within it for the `scss` so:

```
copy: {
    dist: {
        files: [{
            expand: true,
            cwd:'<%= app %>/',
            src: ['main-folder/**', '!**/*.scss', '!main-folder/folder-X/**', '!main-folder/folder-Y/**'],
            dest: '<%= dist %>/'
        }]
    },
},
```

Comment: You have probably already tried this but what if you add a trailing `/` to the omitted directories in the list?

Comment: yes, it does work on scss files. Still not working with the trailing slash

Comment: trailing `/**`? if that doesnt work im out haha sorry